# Dice rolling game outputs incorrect information

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is basically a dice rolling game, but at the end, the code is meant to state how far ahead player 1 beat player 2, but the code outputs random integers that I believe don't correlate to anything

```
    import random
    Round = int(input("Developer use only, set to 5 otherwise "))
    p1_extra = 0
    p1_total = 0
    p1_turns = 5
    p2_extra = 0
    p2_total = 0
    p2_turns = 5
    for i in range (Round):
        p1_go = input("Please type 'ROll' to roll the dice, Player One ")
        while p1_go != ("ROLL"):
            p1_go = input("Please type 'Roll' to roll the dice. (caps sensitive)")
        p1_roll_1 = random.randint(1,6)
        p1_roll_2 = random.randint(1,6)
        p1_add = (p1_roll_1) + (p1_roll_2)
        p1_total = p1_add + p1_total
        print ("P1: On your first roll you got " , p1_roll_1 , ". On your second roll you got " , p1_roll_2 , ". In total you have " , p1_total)
       
        
    if p1_total % 2 == 0:
        print ("Player One Got An Extra 10 Points For Getting An Even Number! ")
        p1_total = (p1_total) + 10
        print ("Player Ones Total Is Now " , p1_total)
    else:
        print ("Player One Lost 5 Points For Getting An Odd Number! ")
        p1_total = (p1_total) - 5
        print ("Player ones Total Is Now " , p1_total)

    if p2_total % 2==0:
        print ("Player Two Got An Extra 10 Points For Getting An Even Number! ")
        p1_total = (p2_total) + 10
        print ("Player Twos Total Is Now " , p2_total)
    else:
        print ("Player Two Lost 5 Points For Getting An Odd Number! ")
        p1_total = (p1_total) - 5
        print ("Player Twos Total Is Now " , p2_total)
        
    if p1_total > p2_total:
        print ("Player 1 Won. Congratulations!!! ")
        difference = (p1_total) - (p2_total)
        print ("Player 2 was " , difference , " points away from drawing ")
    else:
        print ("Player 2 Won. Congratulations!!! ")
        difference = (p2_total) - (p1_total)
        print ("Player 1 was " , difference , " points away from drawing ")
```

Expected results are meant to be the difference between player one's final score and player two's final scores, but the code outputs a different number, never correct to the expected outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in your code and you are not actually updating your `p2_total` correctly. You are assigning the value to `p1_total` instead. Try changing the following lines:

```
if p2_total % 2==0:
    print ("Player Two Got An Extra 10 Points For Getting An Even Number! ")
    p2_total = (p2_total) + 10          # Renamed this line
    print ("Player Twos Total Is Now " , p2_total)
else:
    print ("Player Two Lost 5 Points For Getting An Odd Number! ")
    p2_total = (p2_total) - 5           # Renamed this line
    print ("Player Twos Total Is Now " , p2_total)
```

Comment: haha, it works now. thank you so much. i feel like such an idiot :)

Comment: Don’t worry, happens to the best of us. Also as it looks like you’re new to StackOverflow, it’s a common courtesy for both the people that put time into answering your question and future viewers to select the answer that was most helpful rather than leaving the question “unanswered”.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt know how to mark it as answered. Thank you so much. is there any way i could contact you directly instead of posting here?

Comment: @KamilLeocadie-Olsen Unfortunately, I don't believe it's possible to contact someone directly on SO aside from within the context of a specific question.